# Table slightly breaks when zooming in and out of page

Tags: html, css, html-table, html-email

I am using tables to structure a HTML email.

When I view the page at 90% zoom (on Chrome), my tables look fine. But when I zoom to 100% and beyond, my table shifts by a few pixels, and I don't know why.

**90% Zoom**:

[image]

**100% Zoom (and beyond)**:

[image]

I want each `td` to have `max-height: 286px; max-width:332px;` and have set it up that why, but it still breaks beyond these parameters, why?

```html
<table bgcolor="#0a1219" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="max-width:692px;background-color:#0a1219;" width="692">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <!------------->
      <!-- IMAGE 1 -->
      <td align="center" style="font-family:'Open Sans',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; max-height: 286px; max-width:332px;" valign="bottom">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <!-- IMAGE -->
              <td align="right" style="font-family:'Arial',Helvetica,sans-serif;">
                <a href="#" target="_blank">
                  <img alt="Image-1" src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/3055391/Inbound/CPD%202017/Email/Newsletter%20%20-%20Customers/block-1.png" style="display:block;border:0px;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;color:#ffffff" height="284">
                </a>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <!------------->
      <!-- IMAGE 2 -->
      <td align="left" style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;padding-right:22px; max-height: 286px; max-width:332px;" valign="bottom">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
          <tbody>
            <!--ROW 1 IMAGE -->
            <tr>
              <td align="center" style="font-family:'Open Sans',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; background-color:#00adf2;">
                <img alt="Speech marks" src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/3055391/Inbound/CPD%202017/Email/Newsletter%20%20-%20Customers/speech.png" style="display:block;border:0px;font-family:Arial, Helvetica,sans-serif;color:#ffffff; padding-top: 3px;" width="310">
              </td>
            </tr>
            <!--ROW 1 TEXT -->
            <tr>
              <td align="center" style="background-color:#00adf2; font-family:Arial;font-size:14px;line-height:20px;color:#fff; text-align: center;">
                Faceate volorunt uta quo moditas
                <br> et labo. Comnima iorehent hit est
                <br> am vit elit volores cimpossime
                <br> serchit, oditiis rehenis volor
                <br> sequisqui ut late cus. Faceate
                <br> volorunt uta quo moditas et labo.
                <br> Comnima ioreh.
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <!--ROW 3 LINE -->
              <td align="center" style="font-family:'Open Sans',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;padding: 22px;background-color:#00adf2;vertical-align:top;">
                <!-- NESTED TABLE -->
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td align="center" style="font-family:'Open Sans',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; width: 100%;" width="100%">
                        <!-- TABLE FOR LINE -->
                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                          <tbody>
                            <tr>
                              <td align="center" bgcolor="#fff" height="3" style="height:4px;width:50px;font-size:0px;" width="50"></td>
                            </tr>
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                        <td style="padding-bottom:18px;"></td>
                        <!-- TABLE FOR LINE END -->
                      </td>
                      <!-- LINE END -->
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
                <!-- NESTED TABLE END -->
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>

      <!-- FIRST ROW CLOSE -->
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Edit**:

**When I remove a line from the text**:

[image]

Comment: When it breaks the layout, try to remove some words from the copy and see if the issue is related to the number of lines.

Comment: When I remove a line, the whole td falls down. I've added an image to the question to show what I mean.

Comment: also you had an padding-top: 3px; at the 2nd image

Comment: @Constantin ah yes, I've removed that, but now the situation is reversed. The image of the man is higher than the the second blue block?

Comment: i'm trying to convert all whole your tables in divs

Comment: @Constantin - I want to avoid divs. As mentioned, this is for a HTML email. Many email clients break layouts if div's are involved.

Comment: Also, your table has a wrong nesting hierarchy... There is a `<td style="padding-bottom:18px;"></td>` in the wrong position, or the sibling table is in the wrong place.

Comment: DO not use DIVs. Code like it's 2002. max-height and max-width are seriously problematic, and you are better off just setting a hard width/height inside your tables.

Answer (score 0):

here i try your code in internet explorer and firefox x64 ,i don't have chrome (for me is useless as ie is)!
**here was only a valign problem** how you see pressing the button Run COde Snippet

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="Generator" content="EditPlus® editplus.com DA BEST EDITOR IN THE WORLD FROM SOUTH KOREA">
  <title>MY STUPID FIX</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <table bgcolor="#0a1219" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="max-width:692px;background-color:#0a1219;" width="692">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <!------------->
      <!-- IMAGE 1 -->
      <td align="center" style="font-family:'Open Sans',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; max-height: 286px; max-width:332px;" valign="top">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <!-- IMAGE -->
              <td align="right" style="font-family:'Arial',Helvetica,sans-serif;">
                <a href="#" target="_blank">
                  <img alt="Image-1" src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/3055391/Inbound/CPD%202017/Email/Newsletter%20%20-%20Customers/block-1.png" style="display:block;border:0px;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;color:#ffffff" height="284">
                </a>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <!------------->
      <!-- IMAGE 2 -->
      <td align="left" style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;padding-right:22px; max-height: 286px; max-width:332px;" valign="top">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
          <tbody>
            <!--ROW 1 IMAGE -->
            <tr>
              <td align="center" style="font-family:'Open Sans',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; background-color:#00adf2;">
                <img alt="Speech marks" src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/3055391/Inbound/CPD%202017/Email/Newsletter%20%20-%20Customers/speech.png" style="display:block;border:0px;font-family:Arial, Helvetica,sans-serif;color:#ffffff;" width="310">
              </td>
            </tr>
            <!--ROW 1 TEXT -->
            <tr>
              <td align="center" style="background-color:#00adf2; font-family:Arial;font-size:14px;line-height:20px;color:#fff; text-align: center;">
                Faceate volorunt uta quo moditas
                <br> et labo. Comnima iorehent hit est
                <br> am vit elit volores cimpossime
                <br> serchit, oditiis rehenis volor
                <br> sequisqui ut late cus. Faceate
                <br> volorunt uta quo moditas et labo.
                <br> Comnima ioreh.
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <!--ROW 3 LINE -->
              <td align="center" style="font-family:'Open Sans',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;padding: 22px;background-color:#00adf2;vertical-align:top;">
                <!-- NESTED TABLE -->
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td align="center" style="font-family:'Open Sans',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; width: 100%;" width="100%">
                        <!-- TABLE FOR LINE -->
                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                          <tbody>
                            <tr>
                              <td align="center" bgcolor="#fff" height="3" style="height:4px;width:50px;font-size:0px;" width="50"></td>
                            </tr>
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                        <td style="padding-bottom:18px;"></td>
                        <!-- TABLE FOR LINE END -->
                      </td>
                      <!-- LINE END -->
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
                <!-- NESTED TABLE END -->
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>

      <!-- FIRST ROW CLOSE -->
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
 </body>
</html>
```